# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 error EF Core

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am building an application using .NET5, and I am trying to use the EF Core update-migrations and I get the following error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

By viewing similar posts, I figured my `connectionstring` is the problem. However I cant seem to find the correct string to use. If I look at the properties of my localDB it says its `connectionstring` is:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

I set it to be DefaultConnection `appsettings.json` and connect like this in `startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Went trough uninstalling SQL Express first, for then to be given this string after installation:

```
Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

After installing localDB again I fixed the issue by modifying the connectionstring to:

```
Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Answer (score 2):

[.UseSqlServer(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions_UseSqlServer_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder_System_String_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder__) expects a connection string, not the name of a configuration parameter.

```
connectionString 
String 
The connection string of the database to connect to.
```

So you must fetch the connection string from your configuration and pass it to `.UseSqlServer`.  For instance in ASP.NET there's a Startup class with an [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instance you can use.  EG

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: I already tried that, but when I go with this I get the error:
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Comment: Then you have a configuration issue, not an EF issue.

Comment: Any ideas? I have tried many things.
If I go with the version you provided, I cant even add-migration. I can do that with my version

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your start project is on multiple projects. be sure just a main project is started. after building the project, you can select some projects to start again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QNVF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've got that error because of some programming mistake I made in the `Data/MyAppDbContext.cs`

In my case, modifying the code into the following one made that error go away.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Data
{
    // DbContext is a session within the DB
    public class MyAppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyAppsDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyAppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        // Any entity you may use.
        public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```